# How to disable scrolling in ScrollViewer in AvaloniaUI?

Tags: c#, avaloniaui, avalonia

I am using MapControl(MapsUI) in ScrollViewer in my AvaloniaUI 11.0.5. app. I need to disable scrolling in ScrollViewer while pointer is in MapControll. I have tried this code but it did not work:

AXAML:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="mainPanel">
...
<Panel PointerEntered="disableScroll" PointerExited="enableScroll" Name="MapBox" /> //here is MapControl added later in code
...
///some very big stuff here like Panels, TextBoxes, Images etc.
...
</ScrollViewer>
```

c#:

```
private void disableScroll(object o, PointerEventArgs e)
{
    mainPanel.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = Avalonia.Controls.Primitives.ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;
}

private void enableScroll(object o, PointerEventArgs e)
{
    mainPanel.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = Avalonia.Controls.Primitives.ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
}
```

Maybe is there some pre-scroll event?
Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After very long time I found a solution.

I created function:

```
private void MapControl_PointerWheelChanged(object sender, PointerWheelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

and and assigned it to MapControl in axaml:

```
<avalonia:MapControl Name="Map" PointerWheelChanged="MapControl_PointerWheelChanged"/>
```

Now I can zoom in and out the Map without scrolling the ScrollViewer at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to scroll in a `ScrollViewer` can be controlled by the visibility of the ScrollBar itself.

```xml
<ScrollViewer Name="MyScrollViewer">
```

```cs
private void DisableScroll()
{
    MyScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;
}

private void EnableScroll()
{
    MyScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible; // Or Auto if prefered.
}
```

You can also bind this in XAML if you prefer an MVVM approach.

**WARNING**: Hiding the Scrollbar does **not** disable scrolling using the mouse wheel.  Only `ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled` will stop all scrolling.  Though you might be able to achieve a Disabled Hidden effect using a style and a [Property Equals](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/styling/selectors#propertyequals) selector.

Comment: Yes, this seems to do the trick. But after disabling scrolling I am not able to enable it any more. ScrollBarVisibility.Visible neither Auto do nothing. Any solutions here?

Comment: @AdamA please update your original issue to include the updated code from this answer and we can take a look.

Comment: Sure, code is updated now

Comment: @AdamA Your disable method name doesn't match the name in XAML.  Other than that, it works fine when I try it.  Keep in mind, if the panel is being stretched to fill the window, you may not get the exit event.  Also the control in the panel may be handling the exit event before it bubbles up to the panel, depending on the control.

Comment: Disable method name was just spelling mistake I did in this post, I fixed it. I found out that enabling and disabling scrolling works well. When cursursor moves in and out panel it works fine. But when I scroll in map control (that is inside panel) scrolling won't enable anymore. This happens only when scrollviewer has place to move. When the scrollviewer is at the top of window and I zoom in on the map, after leaving the cursor, the scrollviewer can be scrolled. But when I zoom out map (in this case scrollviewer has place to move down) after leaving it, scrollviewer won't scroll anymore.